# How could we design database for table job subjob and contract?

Tags: database, relational-database

the relationship between table is following this
1 job may contain 0-M subjob = 1 : M
0-M subjob may have 0-M contract = M :M
the table I design are

Job                  :JobID

Subjob:SubjobID

Contract:ContractID

Subjob_Contract:SubjobID,ContractID

The problem I have face is
when we want to view Job and contract.....incase Job doesnt have Subjob so how could contract link with Job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would eliminate the distinction between a job and a SubJob from the table structure. You could use the SubJob table as a link to to other Jobs, then you only have a Job_Contract reference.

SubJob would then contain a link between all Jobs and their SubJobs.

```
Subjobs:
 parent_job_id -- Reference to parent Job
 job_id -- Previously, your SubJobId
```

Example:

```
Select * from subjobs where subjobs.parent_job = {jobid};
```

Return a set of all subjobs which contain "subjobid"s that are actually job id's.

This way you can reference a contract from any job.

Comment: Thank you actually i think of it first but i got confuse. i would explain you like this                                                 ex. I have one job name : A and I have subjob name A1 and A2 both of the subjob have the same contract name C in the linking table will  have first record is job "A" and Contract "C" the second record is job"A" and Contract "C". so how can we differentiat between two job of this

Comment: @ Mike M :from my curious above, is it going to overwrite?

Comment: The link table would contain the A1 and A2 records, which would then be used to locate a record in the main Job table, which would then reference the Contract "C".